# [How deduce from shadows, the angulation of the Sun that the Sun is 15 degrees over horizon?

Tags: sun

At [r/rbi](https://redd.it/gh282b), u/A11edge asked

> Can anyone determine an hour when the photo was taken?
>
> The author of the photo is suspected of spraying pesticides during daytime (which is illegal because it causes death of thousands of bees).
>
> Location: somewhere in Poland

[image]

XauManKib answered

> Judging by the photo, I can see three main aspects: the flowers, the shadows and the upper reflection of the Sun.
>
> Considering the colour of the sky and the overall light, this is the afternoon.
>
> The flowers in the picture are Cruciferae, and I thinks is white mustard, common in East Europe, that is flowering between April and May, this means that the sunset in Poland, is around 1930 hours and 2020 hours in that period.
>
> **Supported by the shadows, the angulation of the Sun is clear in the reflection present in the photo, that is raffigurating [I looked up on [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/raffigurare#Italian)], except flares, the Sun as [typo for "is"] 15 degrees over the horizon, or about 40 minutes before the sunset.**
> The time in the photo is between 1850 and 1940 hours.

1. I never visited Poland and don't know anything on it. But can someone explain boldened paragraph like I'm 5 in Simple English? How  deduce all this?
2. There are "**flares**"?
3. "**the angulation of the Sun is clear in the reflection present in the photo**"? Can someone draw on the picture to indicate this?
4. How deduce the Sun is 15 degrees over the horizon?
5. How deduce "**40 minutes before the sunset**"?

Comment: I can't tell the angle from the image, but i can tell that 15° is an hour because 24*15 = 360, once around, a day. Buuuut ... the yellow ball does not sink and rise vertically but on an arc determined by the latitude and the season (axis tilt). A little trigonometry will help, i won't spoil you the fun :-) p.s.: Sure its not canola ? Rafienry, biofuel and all that ? Darn monoculture ...

Comment: ... or just look up daytime length for mid April. It changes quickly and a few minutes are decisive !

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the shadow of the tractor on the right side of the exhaust pipe you can see that this picture is taken in the early morning or a fairly short time before sunset.

It is not possible to give you a good estimate of what time the picture is taken as this depends on the time of year.

If the picture is taken in early april it is more than one hour before sunset and more than one hour after sunrise.

If the picture is taken in the middle of may it might be whitin one hour before sunset or one hour after sunrise.